# My PHP form works on my godaddy hosted website, but will not work on a yahoo hosted website, how can I correct this?

Tags: php

This form is for a website hosted on yahoo. I know it accepts php because I ran and test.php and it went through. The form goes nowhere after hitting submit on the yahoo website. I uploaded to another site and got an error message that says " Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_OLD_FUNCTION or T_FUNCTION or T_VAR or '}' in /home/ecdo02/public_html/emag/validate.class.php on line 4". So I tried it on my own website hosted by godaddy and no errors, the form went through successfully and it showed up in my email. Does anyone have an idea what's going on? Its very strange.

This is my request.php

```
<?php
define("EMAIL", "xxxxxxx@xxxxx.com");

 if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

 include('validate.class.php');

//assign post data to variables
$firstname = trim($_POST['firstname']);
$lastname = trim($_POST['lastname']);
$company = trim($_POST['company']);
$address = trim($_POST['address']);
$city = trim($_POST['city']);
$state = trim($_POST['state']);
$zip = trim($_POST['zip']);
$email = trim($_POST['email']);
$phone = trim($_POST['phone']);
$fax = trim($_POST['fax']);
$title = trim($_POST['title']);
$interest = trim($_POST['interest']);
$comment = trim($_POST['comment']);

//start validating our form
$v = new validate();
$v->validateStr($firstname, "firstname", 3, 75);
$v->validateStr($lastname, "lastname", 3, 75);
$v->validateEmail($email, "email");
$v->validateStr($phone, "phone");
$v->validateStr($comment, "comment", 10, 500); 



//use php's mail function to send the email
    @mail($email_to, $subject ,$message ,$header ); 

    if(!$v->hasErrors()) {
    $header = "From: $email\n" . "Reply-To: $email\n";
    $subject = "Lead from Website";
    $email_to = EMAIL;

    $message = "A message was submitted.

    From: $title $firstname $lastname
    Company: $company

    Address: $address
    City: $city
    State/ Province/ Region: $state
    Postal/ Zip Code: $zip

    E-mail: $email
    Phone: $phone
    Fax: $fax

    What would you like? $interest

    Comments:
    $comment

    -End of message
    "; 


//grab the current url, append ?sent=yes to it and then redirect to that url
    $url = "http". ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? "s" : "") . "://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    header('Location: '.$url."?sent=yes");

    } else {
//set the number of errors message
$message_text = $v->errorNumMessage();      

//store the errors list in a variable
$errors = $v->displayErrors();

//get the individual error messages
$firstnameErr = $v->getError("firstname");
$lastnameErr = $v->getError("lastname");
$phoneErr = $v->getError("phone");
$emailErr = $v->getError("email");
$commentErr = $v->getError("comment");
}//end error check
}
// end isset

 ?>
```

This is my validate.class.php

```
<?php
class validate {

  public $errors = array();

  public function validateStr($postVal, $postName, $min = 1, $max = 500) {
if(strlen($postVal) < intval($min)) {
  $this->setError($postName, ucfirst($postName)." field is required.");
} else if(strlen($postVal) > intval($max)) {
  $this->setError($postName, ucfirst($postName)." must be less than {$max} characters long.");
  }
 }// end validateStr


  public function validateEmail($emailVal, $emailName) {
if(strlen($emailVal) <= 0) {
  $this->setError($emailName, "Please enter an e-mail address");
} else if (!preg_match('/^[^0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*[@][a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-   zA-Z0-9_]+)*[.][a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/', $emailVal)) {
  $this->setError($emailName, "Please enter a valid e-mail address");
    }
   }// end validateEmail


  /* Validate phone no to allow numbers only */    
    public function validatePhone($phoneVal, $phoneName) {
    if (strlen($phoneVal) <= 0) {
        $this->setError($phoneName, "Please enter your phone number"); 
    } else if (preg_match('/[^0-9]/', $phoneVal)) { 
        $this->setError($phoneName, "Please enter a valid phone number");
    }
} // end validatephone



 /* sets an error message for a form element*/   
  private function setError($element, $comment) {
$this->errors[$element] = $comment;
}



  /* returns the error of a single form element*/ 
  public function getError($elementName) {
if($this->errors[$elementName]) {
  return $this->errors[$elementName];
  } else {
  return false;
  }
 }

 /* displays the errors as an html un-ordered list*/ 
 public function displayErrors() {
$errorsList = "<ul class=\"errors\">\n";
foreach($this->errors as $value) {
  $errorsList .= "<li>". $value . "</li>\n";
}
$errorsList .= "</ul>\n";
return $errorsList;
}


/* returns whether the form has errors*/
public function hasErrors() {
if(count($this->errors) > 0) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
}



 /* returns a string stating how many errors there were*/
  public function errorNumMessage() {
if(count($this->errors) > 1) {
        $message = "There were " . count($this->errors) . " errors sending your message!\n";
    } else {
        $message = "There was an error sending your message!\n";
    }
return $message;
 }// end hasErrors

}// end class

?>
```

Here is the form

```
    <form id="contact_form" method="post" action="request.php">

                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Thank You</legend>
                      <div style="padding-left:100px">    

                        <?php if(isset($_GET['sent'])): ?><table width="590" border="0">
    <tr>
<td width="590" colspan="2"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
<td colspan="2">
  <div style="padding:30px; text-align:center"><span style="font-size:24px; font-weight:bold;     ">Thank You!<br /><br /><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:15px; background:; padding:20px; width:300px;text-align:center">Your submission has been submitted.</span></div>
  </td>
   </tr>
   </table></div><?php endif; ?>
  </fieldset>





                   <fieldset>
                        <legend>Request</legend>
                      <div style="padding-left:100px">    

                        <table width="590" border="0">
    <tr>
<td colspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
<td colspan="2"></td>
</tr>
   <tr>
<td width="195"><label>What would you like? </label></td>
<td width="395"><select name="interest">
  <option value=""> -- Please select -- </option>
  <option>Add me to your mailing list.</option>
  <option>Send me an information kit.</option>
  <option>Call me to set up a meeting.</option>
  </select></td>
    </tr>
  </table></div>
 </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>
                 <legend>Personal Info</legend>
                   <div style="padding-left:100px;"> 
                     <table width="590" border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="5">
                          <tr>
                            <td width="195" align="right"><label><b>Title</b></label></td>
                            <td width="395"><select name="title" style="width:183px">
  <option value=""> - Select Your Title - </option>
  <option>Mr.</option>
  <option>Mrs.</option>
  <option>Miss</option>
  <option>Ms.</option>
  <option>Dr.</option>
  <option>Prof.</option>
  <option>Rev.</option>
  <option>Other</option>
</select>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td align="right"><label><b>First Name</b><span style="color: red">        *</span></label></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo htmlentities($firstname); ?>" />                                <br /></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td><span class="errors"><?php echo $firstnameErr; ?></span></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td align="right"><label><b>Last Name<span style="color: red">        *</span></b></label></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="lastname" value="<?php echo htmlentities($lastname); ?>" />                                  <br /></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td><span class="errors"><?php echo $lastnameErr; ?></span></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                             <td><label><b>Company</b></label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="company"  value="<?php echo htmlentities($company); ?>" /></td>

                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                       </tr>
                          <tr>
                             <td><label><b>Street Address</b><span style="color: red"> *</span>      </label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="address"  value="<?php echo htmlentities($address); ?>" /></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td><span class="errors"><?php echo $addressErr; ?></span></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                       </tr>
                          <tr>
                             <td><label><b>City</b><span style="color: red"> *</span></label>       </td>
<td><input type="text" name="city" value="<?php echo htmlentities($city); ?>" /></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td><span class="errors"><?php echo $cityErr; ?></span></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td><label><b>State</b><span style="color: red"> *</span></label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="state"  value="<?php echo htmlentities($state); ?>" />      <br /></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td><span class="errors"><?php echo $stateErr; ?></span></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td><label><b>Postal/Zip Code</b><span style="color: red"> *</span>            </label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="zip"  value="<?php echo htmlentities($zip); ?>" />      <br /></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td><span class="errors"><?php echo $zipErr; ?></span></td>
                          </tr>
                     </table></div>

                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Contact Info</legend>
                       <div style="padding-left:100px;"> 

                        <table width="590" border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="5">
    <tr>
      <td><label><b>E-mail</b><span style="color: red"> *</span></label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="email"  value="<?php echo htmlentities($email); ?>" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><span class="errors"><?php echo $emailErr; ?></span></td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
<td><label><b>Phone</b><span style="color: red"> *</span></label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="phone" value="<?php echo htmlentities($phone); ?>" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td><span class="errors"><?php echo $phoneErr; ?></span></td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
      <td width="195"><label><b>Fax</b></label></td>
          <td width="395"><input type="text" name="fax" value="<?php echo htmlentities($fax); ?>" />
    </td>
      </tr>
     </table></div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>
                           <legend>Additional Notes</legend>

                       <div style="padding-left:100px;"> 

                        <table width="590" border="0" cellpadding="10">
         <tr valign="top">
       <td width="195"><label><b>Your Comment:</b></label></td>
         <td width="395"><textarea name="comment" rows="10" cols="50" style="width: 300px;"/>
      <?php echo htmlentities($comment); ?></textarea><br />
  <span class="errors"><?php echo $commentErr ?></span><br /></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td> 
    <td>
  </td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
     </tr>
 <tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="button" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
                        </table>
        </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: don't validate the email address with a regex, use `filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` instead... trust me

Comment: I've seen this question posted now at least 3 times.  Why do you keep posting the same question over and over?

Comment: The Yahoo server is running an older version of PHP which can't handle the new syntax. Sounds like PHP 4 there. Figure out how to switch the Yahoo server to use a newer PHP version.

Comment: I didn't mean to post the question over, I wasn't trying to get my form to work since I know it works its was more understanding why it won't work on one host and work perfectly fine on another host. I thought maybe it was a php version issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have check phpinfo() on both Yahoo and GoDaddy servers? I'll expect your Yahoo server runs with PHP 4.x while your GoDaddy server runs with PHP 5.x.

Comment: PHP4? Are you kidding? Yahoo employed Lerdorf until 2009, it stands to reason they have a pretty solid, and tailored installment of PHP5

Comment: I checked and it has the latest version of PHP 5.3 so it's not a version issue it seems.

Comment: Well, what kind of error would you expect on the line `public $errors = array();`? The difference in PHP 4 to 5 is `var $errors` to `public $errors`.